# Set datasource 'ALL' for all grails domain mapping GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to add other datasource to use with GORM.

**DataSource.groovy**

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        username = "usrcastor"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbcastor_master"
        password = "castor"
        dialect = net.sf.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        pooled = true
        loggingSql = false


    }

    dataSource_otherDataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        username = "usrcastor"
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbcastor_child_a"
        password = "castor"
        dialect = net.sf.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        pooled = true
        loggingSql = false
    }
}
```

But already have a lot of domain classes and I no have time to define static mapping in each one.

**Domain.groovy**

```
static mapping {
    datasource 'ALL'
}
```

Is posible to configurate grails to set datasource 'ALL' for all domains?

Answer (score 2):

You can add something like this to *grails-app/conf/application.groovy*

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    datasource 'ALL'
}
```

See the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.7/ref/Database%20Mapping/Usage.html) for Grails mappings.

Comment: Properties like `id generator: 'sequence'` works fine but ignore `datasource 'ALL' `

Comment: That is ignored in grails 2.4.3 for me if.